# Running angular tests with karma and jasmine: minErr error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write a basic test for an angular controller. I use the Jasmine framework and karma as a test runner. My test fails with the following error:

```
Firefox 35.0.0 (Linux) MessageCtrl should get the correct message FAILED
    minErr/<@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular.js:78:12
    loadModules/<@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular.js:3906:15
    forEach@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular.js:325:9
    loadModules@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular.js:3872:5
    createInjector@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular.js:3812:11
    workFn@/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/angular-mocks.js:2172:44
    env.executeFiltered@/home/jenselme/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:126:7
    createStartFn/<@/home/jenselme/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171:5
    [2]</Karma/this.loaded@http://localhost:9877/karma.js:185:7
    @http://localhost:9877/context.html:47:5

    TypeError: $scope is undefined in /home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/MessageCtrl.spec.js (line 11)
    @/home/jenselme/tests/javascript/angular/unit_tests/MessageCtrl.spec.js:11:5
    env.executeFiltered@/home/jenselme/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:126:7
    createStartFn/<@/home/jenselme/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171:5
    [2]</Karma/this.loaded@http://localhost:9877/karma.js:185:7
    @http://localhost:9877/context.html:47:5
```

Here is my MessageCtrl.js:

```
var app = angular.module("lastLine", []);

app.controller('MessageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.getMessage = function(name) {
    return 'Hello ' + name;
    };
}]);
```

And my MessageCtrl.spec.js:

```
describe('MessageCtrl', function() {
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(module('MessageCtrl'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('MessageCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));

    it('should get the correct message', function() {
        var message = $scope.getMessage('Cedric');
        expect(message).toBe('Hello Cedric');
    })
});
```

I have no idea where that might come from. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT 1: correct the code of MessageCtrl.spec.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The code in MessageCtrl.spec.js was wrong. The line `beforeEach(module('MessageCtrl'));` should be `beforeEach(module('lastLine'));`